# Add Carbone to Docker image

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I have installed [Carbone](https://github.com/Ideolys/carbone) on my local Linux machine using the following command and it is working properly.

```
npm install carbone
```

Now, I need to add carbone in my docker image, but I don't know how to add it to the image. Should I add the `npm install` command to DockerFile or add it to package.json?

I got the following error if I don't add carbone to docker image:

```
Code : const carbone = require('carbone');
Error: Cannot find module 'carbone'
```

Comment: Now you need to install it in docker in your image. Even on alpine you can install npm then `npm install carbone`. What you did on your local linux machine is (almost) irrelevant to docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carbone have to be used on node projects. You can install through NPM:

```
npm install carbone --save
```

Then, you must follow the documentation of the basics:
https://github.com/Ideolys/carbone/#getting-started

If you want to dockerize your application, you can start your container from the image ideolys/carbone-env-docker. It's a ready to go node:8 image with Libreoffice installed. Example of Dockerfile:

```
FROM ideolys/carbone-env-docker

ENV DIR /app

WORKDIR ${DIR}

COPY . ${DIR}

RUN npm install

# index.js should call carbone functions to generate your report.
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Finally you can build and run the container !
If you need more help or encounter an issue, post an issue on the [Carbone Github](https://github.com/Ideolys/carbone/issues).